# SlickNav responsive menu not appearing

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design, slicknav

I was trying to add slicknav responsive menu on my site, but it doesn't appear. I followed the instructions on homepage.

My html

```
<div class ="container-fluid" >
    <div class="row">
        <div class="hidden-sm col-md-1 col-lg-2"></div>
        <ul class="col-sm-12 col-md-10 col-lg-8" id="menubar">
            <li><a href="{{ root }}">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{ root }}blog">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{ root }}projects">Projects</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{ root }}bio">Bio</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="hidden-sm col-md-1 col-lg-2"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And css

```
.slicknav_menu {
    display:none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 40em) {

    .js #menubar {
        display:none;
    }

    .js .slicknav_menu {
        display:block;
    }
}
```

All the js is loaded in the bottom of the page like this

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-JmvOoLtYsmqlsWxa7mDSLMwa6dZ9rrIdtrrVYRnDRH0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" scr="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.slicknav.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
    $('#menubar').slicknav();
});
</script>
```

Here's my code in JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/w1gudnn8/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I got your point in jsfiddle link. Jquery is not load or can't reach
>   there. no problem i solve it. you can collect it from jsfiddle link listed below
>    
>   [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/o7ykmtso/)

Comment: I think Rajesh is right. Why is he getting down voted? Your slicknav.min.js is not getting loaded.

Comment: Yeah, I found the problem, I needed to load modernizr.js

Comment: Valius, slicknav.min.js was loading just fine, but I needed modernizr.js